# create multiple pdfs and zip Angular 4

Tags: angular, pdf, zip

I have a requirement in which I search for a day and display a "document" for each client based on their usage for the day. I have a button in which I click and will create a single pdf page (or two) for each client and download a zip of all the clients for that day.

Currently I can create a single pdf of all the clients for the day, each client on its own page with Kendo PDF. However I can't seem to find a good method for creating single pdfs for each client. Any recommendations? Using Angular 4.

Comment: Usually, the generation of PDF on the fly requires the resources of the processor and it tries to transfer it to the backend, but you can also use [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks @OlegUtkin. I'll look into pdfkit to see if it will work with my requirements. I was also looking at HummusJS, but pdfkit looks like a solution closer to what I need.